# issue with PHP/Curl using Auth0

Tags: php, laravel, curl, jwt, auth0

I am attempting to use Auth0 to secure an API on Laravel Framework 8.83.22

I am using this tutorial (machine-to-machine) https://auth0.com/blog/build-and-secure-laravel-api/

Problem:

Curl at the command line works fine:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer ***REMOVED***" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{}" http://localhost:8000/api/weightrecords/4195
```

However, making the call inside a PHP script times out (I've tried longer timeouts with no help).  I get the token fine (SECTION 1 below) but SECTION 2 times out (cURL Error #:Operation timed out after 30000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received).

```
public function test_api()
    {

    //SECTION 1: Get the token
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://**REMOVED***.auth0.com/oauth/token",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"client_id\":\"qDpVdykOlRYkxOdq8J7a2CJ7X7E3WUK8\",\"client_secret\":\"**REMOVED**\",\"audience\":\"**REMOVED**",\"grant_type\":\"client_credentials\"}",            
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "content-type: application/json"
            ),
        ));
        
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        
        curl_close($curl);
        
        if ($err) {
            echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
            $response_array = json_decode($response);
     
            $access_token = "authorization: Bearer " . $response_array->access_token;
            echo $access_token;
        }

    //SECTION 2: Use the token
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
            CURLOPT_URL => "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/weightrecords/4195",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                $access_token
            ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
            echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
            echo $response;
        }

    }
```

.env

```
    AUTH0_STRATEGY=api
    AUTH0_DOMAIN=**REMOVED**.us.auth0.com
    AUTH0_CLIENT_ID=qDpVdykOlRYkxOdq8J7a2CJ7X7E3WUK8
    AUTH0_AUDIENCE=**REMOVED**
    API_IDENTIFIER=**REMOVED**
```

kernal.php

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        //...all the defaults...
        'jwt' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckJWT::class, //<<<<------Added
    ];
```

api.php

```
    Route::apiResource('weightrecords', ApiController::class);
```

CheckJWT.php and auth.php same as in article..

Answer (score 1):

What does `$access_token` look like?

Try using the post data without the escapes. 
You may need to urlencode() the json.  Typically not, but I have had it help with one API.
This is how I begin the trouble shooting process.
Add these options.

```
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT=>10,
CURLOPT_FAILONERROR=>true,
CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT=>true,
```

Get the curl_getinfo:

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
$info = var_export(curl_getinfo($curl),true);
echo $info;
```

You should see the out going request header in $info because of the `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT=>true`.

I have a PHP script where it returns details about the request including Body, $_POST, $_GET, $_REQUEST, $_SERVER

[LINK to see your request details](http://eatled.com/receiveheader.php)
You can use this link as your curl URL.

Comment: That is a great way to start the debug. Thank you.

$access_token looks good.  It = eyJhbG **REMOVED** 0hRctQ 

The 'request_header' => 'GET /api/weightrecords/4195 HTTP/1.1 Host: 127.0.0.1:8000 Accept: */* Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip authorization: Bearer eyJhbG **REMOVED** 0hRctQ ', )

Comment: I'm going down the path of debugging my Auth0 implementation.  it seems when I combine the token with the URL it fails somehow... I'm trying some POSTs now and doing it from JS to see if I can get better insight into the problem.  With the POST (writing data to the db) I'm getting an error "Target class [Auth0\\Login\\Contract\\Auth0UserRepository] does not exist." and if you google this there are a few others reporting similar issues.   More to come but thank you for this very helpful debug info...

Comment: I am starting to wonder if I installed the wrong version of Auth0 (  composer require auth0/login ) as I see a config\auth0.php not a config/laravel-auth0.php as referenced in the article... tracking down now...

Comment: I am not a fan of Laravel.  What API are you working with?  Do you have a link to their documentation?

Comment: I'm attempting to use Auth0 to secure an API for a Laravel app.

I'm using Auth0's "machine-to-machine" approach where the system authenticates and authorizes the app rather than a user. It uses a Client Credentials Flow (OAuth 2.0 RFC 6749, section 4.4), in which a 3rd party app can pass their Client ID and Client Secret to authenticate themselves and get a token from the Laravel app.  See this: https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/client-credentials-flow

Comment: I find thier docs confusing because they munge together Machine to Machine with single page/native apps and in thier examples and blogs its hard to tell which way they are going with the example/blog. 

I used this as a reference https://auth0.com/blog/build-and-secure-laravel-api/ but it seems i came up with the same issue as others Target class [Auth0\Login\Contract\Auth0UserRepository] does not exist.  Thier blog also doesn't align 100% (file names config/auth0.php versus config/laravel-auth0.php).

Comment: I'm now looking for an alternative to Auth0 as debugging it is beyond my skills.... 

Any recommendations on other platforms where I can produce an API key to provide a 3rd party along with my API would be helpful.

Comment: Auth0 docs for Laravel are here https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/laravel/interactive